# gcc - compile for another machine does not work

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, legacy

I'm having following issue:

- I have legacy system - ARM CPU.
- On legacy system I don't have devel libs and also don't have GCC.
- On legacy system I don't have enough resources (mainly RAM and SWAP is not possible) to compile.

I need to compile very simple program that I have source for. When I compile it on another machine that have also ARM CPU (a bit newer) with following GCC commands:

```
gcc -mcpu=arm920t -march=armv4t -o app app.c
```

(-mcpu and -march is set to CPU of legacy system)

When I copy this compiled file to legacy system, make it executable and try to run it I get following message:

```
$ ./app
-sh: ./app: No such file or directory
$ ls -lah
total 237K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    0 Apr  4 07:35 .
drwxr-xr-x  4 root    root    0 Dec 31  1969 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root    root 108K Mar 14 09:23 app
$
```

There is no problem with path, partition is **not** mounted with noexec option. When I copy any system (for example cat) file into same directory I can launch it without problem.

Here is difference between application I compiled (1st result) and application that was already on system (2nd result):

```
$ readelf -h app
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0xa278
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          100104 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x5000002, has entry point, Version5 EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         10
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         38
  Section header string table index: 35
$
```

And:

```
$ readelf -h cat
ELF Header:
  Magic:   7f 45 4c 46 01 01 01 61 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  Class:                             ELF32
  Data:                              2's complement, little endian
  Version:                           1 (current)
  OS/ABI:                            ARM
  ABI Version:                       0
  Type:                              EXEC (Executable file)
  Machine:                           ARM
  Version:                           0x1
  Entry point address:               0x8c34
  Start of program headers:          52 (bytes into file)
  Start of section headers:          15220 (bytes into file)
  Flags:                             0x2, has entry point, GNU EABI
  Size of this header:               52 (bytes)
  Size of program headers:           32 (bytes)
  Number of program headers:         6
  Size of section headers:           40 (bytes)
  Number of section headers:         24
  Section header string table index: 23
$
```

Output of `file cat app`:

```
app: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped
cat: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.0, stripped
```

I'm not sure what's problem here, as even if application is wrongly compiled I'm expecting to get different error message than 'No such file or directory'.

Comment: The 'Version5 ABI' vs 'GNU EABI' may account for some of the trouble.  What does `file cat app` have to say?  If the answer isn't identical, you'll need to track down what's different.

Comment: app: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.16, not stripped  
---
cat: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.2.0, stripped
I can see 3 differences: - My app is no stripped(as far as I know it's not a problem, as even when I stipe it I have same problem.). - My app is having newer GNU/Linux specialization. - For my application there is mentioned SYSV and I have no clue what is that and how can I compile application without it :(

Comment: It looks like the target machine does not have the support needed for the GNU/Linux specialization.  Unless you can find a working binary on the target of the same type, you are out of luck.  Either upgrade te support on the target, or only use what the target already supports..

Answer (score -2):

This problem is mainly due to shared library libc problem.When you compile program on arm machine which has support of gcc is using library (libc) is not the same that your target having. so 1st check your library on both host and target.
To cross check above comment you try out this.

```
gcc -static -o app app.c
```

Now copy your app executable to your target .Execute on target,it will execute without any problem.
to check above code compiled statically. use 
file app 
or
ldd app.

if u dont want to compile statically ,then copy your libraries from /lib of target rootfs
while compiling provide library path to target lib instead of host lib.This can be done by

```
LDFLAGS=-L/<path-to-target-lib>  gcc  -o app app.c
```

Comment: Copying the libraries alone will not resolve the target ABI difference. That's determined by how GCC is configured.